# merge two data frame with column name but give more result before merge file

Tags: r

The first dataframe looks like this

```
Sample ,       chr  ,  start    , stop<br/>
549151236,  , chr20 ,  27100000 , 28172124<br/>
549151236,  ,chr10  , 45479093  , 47547144<br/>
549151236,  ,chr11  , 50366193  , 51284544<br/>
549151236,  ,chr11  , 90945964  , 91030487<br/>
549151236,  ,chr5   , 9954211   ,  9979517<br/>
```

The second dataframe look like

```
Sample  ,event, probe, 
549151236, CN gain, 3
549151236, CN gain , 20
```

It has more columns than the example file.

When I use merge to merge 2 dataframe (with have 3850 row in these two file)

```
testchop=merge(chop_result,newchop, by.x="Sample",by.y="Sample")
```

...it gives me about 315565 row, so how to fix this problem.

Comment: Your problem is that for each set of shared and duplicated Sample values you get the m x n Cartesian product of rows. You may want to rethink what you are asking for. If the rows are completely aligned you may want to use `cbind`. You should make a small test case and experiment.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.Cbind works with it now.

Answer (score 0):

Within merge you have the options `all.x` and `all.y`, this might help....

```
# this will give you all obs which are in both chop_result and newchop
# and only if they are in both (intersection)
merge(chop_result, newchop, by="Sample")

# here all chop_result are in the new data frame, if
# there is a "Sample" number which is not in chop_result
# than it is filled with NA
merge(chop_result, newchop, by="Sample", all.x=TRUE)

# same as above but now all newchop results will be there
merge(chop_result, newchop, by="Sample", all.y=TRUE)
```

hth